# Radial solutions to Possion equation with Robin condition in annulus

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an annulus with inner radius $R_1$ and outer radius $R_2$, and $\beta>0$. Let $u$ solve the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=1\quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}+\beta u=0\quad &\mbox{on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
Is $u$ necessarily radial for every $\beta>0$? If so, is it possible to explicitly write down the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions in $C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ are indeed unique (though, of course, this can get swapped for Sobolev spaces or others if you prefer, but the basic idea is similar).  If you have two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, let $u = u_1 - u_2$, multiply the PDE they satisfy by $u$ and integrate by parts.  You'll find that
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 + \int_{\partial \Omega} \beta |u|^2 =0
$$
and hence that $0 = u = u_1 - u_2$ in $\Omega$.

Once you have uniqueness in hand, you can just propose a radial ansatz and see if it works.  If it does, then that's the solution.  A radial solution $u(x) = v(|x|)$ must satisfy
$$
v''(r) + \frac{(n-1)}{r} v'(r) = -1
$$
and thus
$$
(r^{n-1} v'(r)) ' = - r^{n-1}.
$$
Integrate twice to get the general form with two free coefficients, and then plug into the BCs to determine the coefficients.  I'll leave this to you to work out.

Comment: +1  Great answer. As a small comment for the OP, once you know solutions are unique another method to prove radial symmetry is to prove that $v(x) :=u(  O x)$ is also a solution to the BVP where $O$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix. By uniqueness, this implies that $u$ is invariant under rotations about the origin, so it is radial.

Comment: Yes, good point @JackT.  Thanks for the addition!